# How to select a tab first to reveal the details?

Tags: selection, tabs, checkboxes

Scenario: A customer calls in to a store and places three separate orders using a single account/number. Now he wants to cancel two of them and calls in the store. The store owner picks up and to maintain the records and document the calls he has to first select the orders which the customer wants to cancel from the interface and then fill up few details about it. So he will select two orders out of three and then fill up the details.

For this I was thinking of having three tabs with checkboxes on the interface. The user will first select the order by checking the tab and then can fill up the details. 
But the problem with this design will be if he wants to review any order details by coming back to a tab the checkbox will get unselected i.e. the order will be deselected from documenting.

Suggestions are most welcome with design and approach

[image]

Comment: Two comments: (1) Won't the details already be filled in? The customer has already placed the order. And (2) Why should selecting a tab deselect it? You're designing the interface: if that result is undesirable, don't implement it.

Comment: Is an "order" always a single product in this system?

Comment: 1)The system will capture few details automatically but others like Cancel Reason, Penalty etc. have to filled in.

Comment: 2)Coming back to a tab will actually result the click action to be performed on the checkbox and will result in deselcting it.

Comment: For (2), **only if you code that**. It's possible to say that clicking a tab doesn't change its selected state if you keep a record of what has been selected.

Comment: Any live e.g or prototype so that I can give it a try. I am just not sure about the behavior.

Comment: This is getting dangerously close to begin off-topic by asking how to implement this ability. It should probably be migrated to [StackOverflow](http://www.stackvoerflow.com) along with code that you are currently using.

Comment: Not really. I don't need any code for it neither i want info on how to implement it. I just want to see the behavior from some reference. Screenshots of the states will also do.

Answer (score 3):

I probably wouldn't use tabs; I would use a datagrid displaying all orders at-a-glance given a customer number.  The datagrid would have a checkbox column (or allow multiple row selections) and a button that would perform whatever action against all selected rows.

For order details, if there isn't enough room on the row to show the order and its details, you could do a master/detail datagrid where you click the row and the details expand/collapse, or when clicked, a modal pops up with the details pre-filled where you could have multiple actions on the modal.

Comment: Actually there is not much room on the interface to have a data grid of any sort. It is a 220 px wide form with a vertical scroll and is a pop over from the footer of the application. So data grid and modal cannot be used.

Comment: That information probably would have been useful in the question. =D